# Joining with Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

The UDF(my_udf) I am working on takes JobId as a parameter and returns a table of different candidates(Candidate Id) and their corresponding scores that have applied to the job.

Now I want to display list of all candidates, job they have applied and the corresponding score.
So my query is something like this:

`select * 
from JobANDCandidates jc
inner join Candidates c ON jc.candidateId = c.Id
inner join Jobs j on j.Id = jc.jobId
Cross apply my_udf(jc.JobId)`

But above query takes too much time and is incorrect.

I somehow need to cross apply only to the row returned from UDF based on the candidate ID.
I tried
`CROSS APPLY my_udf(jc.JobId) fun ON/WHERE fun.candidateId = c.Id`, but neither ON clause or WHERE clause works. I get compile error.

Please help

Comment: So the query is not returning the correct results? Perhaps you should figure that out before you even bother with performance. We really can't help much here because at this point there is nothing in the way of details. Table definitions and the function at the very least. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Maybe the cross apply needs to be against a subquery... `cross apply ( select * from my_udf(jc.jabID)` or you need a where cluase specifying how your UDF relates to the other records?

Comment: How about the contents of your function? If this is a multi-statement table valued function it will quite often perform even worse than a scalar function. Bottom line is you are concerned about performance but we can't see any code or table definition.

Comment: Thanks Sean.. That is an already existing function that I intent to use in my query.  The UDF accepts jobId as parameter and returns list of candidates with their scores. In my query I have Candidate table in the join..so I need to only join to the row returned from UDF that has the current candidate Id

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest refactoring the UDF as a simple view, and JOINing to that. Indexes will be applied with the view, so speed should be very good.

IMHO, a UDF is overkill for this type of operation when a normal view can be used, especially if there is ever any concern for portability.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select . . . 
from JobANDCandidates jc inner join
     Candidates c 
     on jc.candidateId = c.Id inner join
     Jobs j
     on j.Id = jc.jobId Cross apply
     dbo.my_udf(jc.JobId) f
where c.id = f.candidateid
```

This assumes that the TVF has a column called `candidateid`.  Otherwise, you might have to specify that with the alias `f(candidateid,  . . .)`.

Note:  This may not have a significant impact on performance, because the query still needs to process the entire TVF.  You might want to allow the function to take a candidate id as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for the reply .But the query still takes a lot of time as the candidate table if huge. I guess I will have to create a new UDF that accepts canidateId.